# My Field Headers Are not showing in my php table

Tags: php, html

I have my php table displaying on my page from a mysql database. They are displayed in order of what Department they are in.

Currently it looks like this:

```
                         Vehicle Department 
                Bob        3234234     bob@acas.com
                Hanna      3434323     Hanna@asas.com
                         Workshop Department
                Andrew     45454523    andrew@aasdasd.com
```

But as you can see the field headers for name,phone and email are not showing. I have tried to echo them along with the database results but it just creates a huge mess within the table.

The final result I am trying to achieve:

```
                        Vehicle Department 
                Name        Phone        Email
                Bob        3234234     bob@acas.com
                Hanna      3434323     Hanna@asas.com
                        Workshop Department
                Name        Phone        Email
                Andrew     45454523    andrew@aasdasd.com
```

So each department will display the field headers for the name,phone,email data from the mysql database. My code can be found below:

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pwd = '*****';

    $database = 'list';
    $table = 'users';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die("Connecting to database failed");

    mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die("Can't select database");

    // sending query
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, email, extension, phone, department FROM {$table} ORDER BY department, name ASC");
    if (!$result) {
        die("Query to show fields from table failed");
    }

    echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

    // printing table rows
    $temp = "";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";

        if ($row['department'] != $temp){
            echo "<td colspan='4' style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold'>{$row['department']}</td></tr>\n<tr>";
            $temp = $row['department'];
        }
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    echo "</table>"
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

The table headers will be displayed below the department names

```
 <?php
        $db_host = 'localhost';
        $db_user = 'root';
        $db_pwd = '*****';

        $database = 'list';
        $table = 'users';

        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die("Connecting to database failed");

        mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die("Can't select database");

        // sending query
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, email, extension, phone, department FROM {$table} ORDER BY department, name ASC");
        if (!$result) {
            die("Query to show fields from table failed");
        }

        echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

        // printing table rows
        $temp = "";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";

            if ($row['department'] != $temp){
                echo "<td colspan='4' style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold'>{$row['department']}</td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>\n";
echo "<tr>";

                $temp = $row['department'];
            }
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        echo "</table>"
    ?>
```

Comment: You are the master sir! Thank you very much ( i actually tried that but put it after the $temp=row line) haha well done ^^

Comment: @J.Hof  Welcome..It will work also if you put it after '$temp=$row['department']` also ...You might have missed to replace the `<tr>` into it... Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function of mysql that is`mysql_field_name` Using this you will be able to get the fields names.
Although its deprecated in php 5.4.0 or above you can check
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php

Comment: Its `mysqli_field` instead of `mysql` pls change it..or they might go wrong

Comment: Yes thats y i have sent link of the new function. Because mysql is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch data from the database, only the actual data is fetched from the server.

So, if you need the table headers to be entered, you can insert the HTML code before the while loop to insert the headers.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '*****';

$database = 'list';
$table = 'users';

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die("Connecting to database failed");

mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, email, extension, phone, department FROM {$table} ORDER BY department, name ASC");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

/********  Add this! *********/
echo '<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>';
/****************************/

// printing table rows
$temp = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    if ($row['department'] != $temp){
        echo "<td colspan='4' style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold'>{$row['department']}</td></tr>\n<tr>";
        $temp = $row['department'];
    }
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
echo "</table>"
?>
```

Comment: That works but I need them to appear on each department. Not just once sir